# my do, while loop not working as i meant :( ( C language)

Tags: c, loops, debugging

hi guys Im  about to finish some c basics course and am ending it with a full calculator project.

at arrays part my following do while loop keeps looping over and over cant break the condition.

I tried to add `exit();`
also changed `return(0)` to `return(EOF)` but nothing happens.

this is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int row_num,colm_num;
    do
    {
        printf("PLEASE! choose Array 'A' Rank (maximum 4x4)==>\n\n");
        printf("  'A' rows=  ");
        scanf("%i", &row_num);

            

       printf("  'A' columns=  ");
        scanf("%i", &colm_num);
        
        printf("Array 'A' set to rank = %ix%i i.e. (A[%i][%i]) \n\n)",row_num,colm_num,row_num,colm_num);
       
    }
    while(( scanf("%i", &row_num)==1 || row_num<=4||row_num>=0)||( scanf("%i", &colm_num)==1 || row_num<=4||row_num>=0)); //restriction for user input 

       
return(0);}
```

I have to mention that this is not the full code but I run this in separate file to debug each section alone btw if there is better way to debug sections of the code than starting another c file tell me  "am using codelite editor IDE" thanks all also am open for any beginners\efficient c coding advices I would be grateful ^^.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `scanf` condition (`scanf("%i", &row_num)==1`) doesn't do quite what you expect it to do. From the scanf manpage:

> RETURN VALUE
> These functions return the number of input items  successfully  matched
> and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the
> event of an early matching failure.

You have one input item being matched, so `scanf` always returns 1 as long as the input was numeric, and you never can exit the loop because the condition remains true.

Call `scanf` to read `row_num` and `col_num` *before* the end of the loop body (checking the return value to signal an error to the user) and then directly check the value of those two variables in the condition.

Alternatively, you could use `&&` instead to verify that `scanf` did indeed read one value, and check the value in the same condition, but this arguably creates an overly messy and hard-to-read condition.

> I run this in separate file to debug each section alone btw if there is better way to debug sections of the code than starting another c file

The best option is to create separate functions, which you can call and test individually from `main` as you test. Once your code matures, you can put all the functions together, and continue to test and debug using tools such as your debugger.

Comment: thanks a lot, got it learned (most of it i believe), i will make this while simpler such as u solution suggestion, but my issue is that i don't want the user to re enter values multiple time especially non-necessary for him only as check for me not to create a bug. unless ure solution will auto skip to while condition with out new user input maybe cuz the same scan func values still in the buffer . but even if user must reenter values!  surly working code\app with two more steps better than nothing XD,

Comment: also i the act of copying each func alone to debug is cuz my main is not only func called and combined together (there is many lines  e.g. 3 switch statements) so in order to come to my new func to debug i ill need to redo all previous inputs. the main  structure is not really very organized (although i tried to XD) i will try to make it easier for debugging in coming codes thanks a lot  again